# get some div text block to show when a plus button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a wordpress costing form but really struggling with the responsive view as ive used text descriptions to explain the products. Is it possible that you know some code where i can put a plus button next to the title of the products. When i press the plus button the small description will show underneath the title.There are multiple products with title and small description. I have done two screenshots to show what i mean  How it looks with small description https://pasteboard.co/xNRq4SCqcYpp.png. How i need it to look https://pasteboard.co/20OrgDInhwWa.png.

I presume it would be an if statement to say if lfb_itemBloc contains lfb_itemDes display none and generate a plus icon and only display lfb_itemDes when plus button is clicked.

The code in question is below

```
<div class="lfb_itemBloc lfb_item lfb_itemContainer_441 lfb_picRow" data-id="441" data-itemtype="picture">

<div data-imagetype="" data-urlvariable="1" data-sentattribute="price" data-       variablename="" data-shadowfx="0" data-html="true" class="lfb_selectable" >

<img data-no-lazy="1" data-tint="false" src="https://testing.secureyourticket.com/wp-content/plugins/WP_Estimation_Form/assets/img/placeholder.png" alt="" class="lfb_selectableImg img .png">
<span class="fas fa-times  icon_select"></span>
</div>

<p class="lfb_imgTitle ">Google Analytics</p><p class="lfb_itemDes " style="
">Set up Google analytics on your site and install tracking codes/tags as needed to view visitors/sessions and site engagement.</p>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Assuming the HTML will get written first and you need to do all this after the fact - first insert the icon, then apply a click action. On that we can find the related description through `.closest()` and `.find()`. Then you can also toggle the font-awesome icon as well.

```js
let insertExpand = `<span class="fa fa-plus expand-icon"></span>`;
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.lfb_itemDes').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() !== '') {
      $(insertExpand).insertBefore($(this).closest('.lfb_item').find('.lfb_imgTitle'));
    }
  })
  $('.expand-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.lfb_item').find('.lfb_itemDes').toggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-plus')) $(this).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    else $(this).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
  })

})
```

```css
.lfb_itemDes {
  display: none;
}

.expand-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.lfb_item {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="lfb_itemBloc lfb_item lfb_itemContainer_441 lfb_picRow" data-id="441" data-itemtype="picture">
  <p class="lfb_imgTitle">Google Analytics</p>
  <p class="lfb_itemDes" style="
">Set up Google analytics on your site and install tracking codes/tags as needed to view visitors/sessions and site engagement.</p>
</div>
<div class="lfb_itemBloc lfb_item lfb_itemContainer_441 lfb_picRow" data-id="441" data-itemtype="picture">
  <p class="lfb_imgTitle">Something else w/ no description</p>

</div>

<div class="lfb_itemBloc lfb_item lfb_itemContainer_441 lfb_picRow" data-id="441" data-itemtype="picture">
  <p class="lfb_imgTitle">Something else w/ description</p>
  <p class="lfb_itemDes" style="
">Blah blah blah.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi kinglish. This seems to be what im looking for but when i enter the code into my custom js section on my wordpress site it doesnt work, should i be entering in jQuery(document).ready(function(){. If You could please recommend how i could load this into wordpress you would be a life saver. Also the plus button is appled to all sections that dont have a description eg their will be sections in the item bloc div that just have a title. Many thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Also this update checks to make sure there is a description in there before adding the icon. You may have to attach this to a hook if the content is being fetched by ajax.

Comment: PS, instead of repeating jQuery all over the place: `jQuery($=> { /* DOM ready and $ alias in scope*/ });`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thankyou Kinglish this was perfect. It worked exactly how i wanted it to

Answer (score 1):

Not so complicated. Among many different ways you may do a variant of the following.

```js
var elmt = document.querySelector(".stg"),
    desc = document.querySelector(".desc");
    
elmt.addEventListener("click", e => desc.style.display = desc.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block");
```

```css
.stg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.stg:after {
  content: " +";
  pointer-events: all;
}
.desc{
  content: "Some Description";
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.67em;
}
```

```html
<div class="stg">Some context</div>
<div class="desc">Description on the topic</div>
```